# Find the probability that in both cases he will also receive a three-digit number

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

> $X$ randomly selects a three-digit decimal number. After that, he
> translates this number into base $9$, and then into base $11$. Find
> the probability that in both cases he will also receive a three-digit
> number.

I solved as follows: I went through many different variants of three-digit numbers and got that for values less than $121$ in the decimal system, two-digit numbers are obtained when converted to the $11$-digit system, and after $728$ in the $10$-digit system, four-digit numbers are obtained in the $9$-digit system. I.e., our conditions are satisfied by numbers from $121$ to $728$, inclusive, i.e. there will be $608$ favorable outcomes. There are only $900$ three-digit numbers in the 10-digit system, so the desired probability is $608/900 = 152/225$. Am I reasoning correctly, or have I made a mistake somewhere? Is there an easier way?

Feel free to edit tags!

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you, but the question of a simpler solution remains valid.

Comment: Can’t think of a simpler method. In the end, you have to count, and there really is only one way to count this question.

Comment: Simpler? $P=\frac{9^3-11^2}{10^3-10^2}$

Comment: To get end points convert $100_{11}$ and $888_9$ to decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct.  $100_{11}=121$ and $888_9=728$ are limits  Therefore the probability is$\frac{728-120}{900}=.67555...$.

Presumably base $11$ extra character counts as a digit.